# Не запускается сохраненный jar файл в intellij idea!! даже через exe ,после launch4j

Tags: java, jar, exe, main

таким образом создал файл.

1. `Intellij Idea >>> File >>> Project Structure >>> Artifacts`
2. `Нажимаете + Выбираете >>>JAR >>> From modules with dependencies >>> Main Class`
3. `Выбираете Main >>> установите галочку на extract to output target JAR >>> OK >>> В Output directry выберите где будет находится файл`
4. `Установите галочку Include in project build >>> установите галочку Show content of element >>> Apply >>> OK`
5. `Затем заходим во вкладку Build >>> Build Artifact >>> выбираете свой проект и жмете Build`

через launch4j создал exe файл ,ничего не происходит.

через командную строку запускаю, ошибка

```
could not find or load main class.
```

открываю файл манифест :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: sample.Main
```

все сходится.

Куда дальше копать?
Может быть настройка в самом проекте?

Comment: Почему не собираешь Maven'ом? Покажи код, структуру проекта или если git публичный, то скинь ссылку. А так гадание на кофейной гуще получается и не удивлен, что нет ответов.

Comment: там очень много классов ..может архивом сбросить или как лучше это делается?(извините недавно начал учиться и не совсем осведомлен)

Comment: Не нужно бросать архив. Нужно изучать git. [Вот](https://githowto.com/ru) относительно неплохой ресурс по изучению git.